# Symfony2 Failed to load resource: [...] 403 (Forbidden) with images in web/uploads/images

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I have some trouble to display images on a web page generated using **Symfony2 and Twig**. I display my images like this :

```
<div style="background-image: url({{ asset('uploads/images/' ~ imageurl) }});">
    <!-- [...] -->
</div>
```

-I have 2 versions :

- **local** (on my computer) : which is working fine.
- **production** : Where I have the error.

-My images are located in `/web/upload/images/`

-I don't think that it is a permission issue because I have the rights on the folder.

```
drwxrwxr-x /web
drwxrwxrwx /web/uploads
drwxrwxrwx /web/uploads/images
drwxrwxrwx /web/uploads/images/*
```

There must be something I didn't configure right but I don't know what I missed...

Comment: Maybe .htaccess file on prod server?

Comment: Did you install your assets with `assets:install` or `assetic:dump`?

Comment: @KhorneHoly I installed the assets using assets:install. Even If I'm not sure of how it works ... :/

Comment: @RafalKozlowski Should I put something in particular in my /web/.htaccess ?

Comment: Are you able to open the same file from URL ? `http://YOU_HOST/web/uploads/images/filename.extension` ?

Comment: @Gauthier not really, just check if nothing is blocking access to the folder.  One more question, how do You install assets? Using symlinks? Maybe you need to update Your Apache configuration in FollowSymlink section and AllowOverride section

Comment: @AlokPatel 'http://MYHOST/web/uploads/images/173056.jpeg' send me 404 not found, and 'http://MYHOST/uploads/images/173056.jpeg' send me 403 forbidden. In the generated code on my web page, I have 'http://MYHOST/uploads/images/173056.jpeg' (403)

Comment: `173056.jpeg` give this file `777` access. That should solve the issue.

Comment: @AlokPatel I just did and i still don't have permission...

Comment: That's weird, may be setting permission 777 of web folder should solve the problem.

Comment: @AlokPatel looks like I already have full reading permission on my web folder. I updated the post with the permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all that is written, it looks like permission issue. Please follow official documentation (as there is no need to copy and paste same text) and  try to fix it. http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

The command `ls` doesn't list hidden files as this one `/web/uploads/.htaccess`. (use `ls -a`)
Someone putted a .htacces with `Deny from all` there...